# Passing arrays / lists between bash functions without global variables

Tags: bash

I have these two functions in a bash script. I am just trying to pass arguments directly from one function to another without using global vars, but I can't seem to do it.

```
function suman {

  NODE_EXEC_ARGS= "--inspect"; 
  __handle_global_suman "${NODE_EXEC_ARGS}" "$@"

}


function __handle_global_suman {

  # I want $1 to be node exec args and $2 to be args to node script
  node $1 ${Z}/cli.js $2;

}
```

**the problem I am having**: in the `__handle_global_suman` function,
the values for `$1` and `$2` seem to represent the original arguments passed to the `suman` function, not the arguments passed to `__handle_global_suman`! I want to be able to access the arguments pass to the `__handle_global_suman` function.

One solution is to use global variables like the following (but this is bad programming in general):

```
NODE_EXEC_ARGS="";  // default
ORIGINAL_ARGS="";  // default

function suman {

  NODE_EXEC_ARGS="--inspect";  
  ORIGINAL_ARGS="$@";  // assume this captures the arguments passed to this function, not the original script...
  __handle_global_suman
}

# ideally there would be a way to make this function truly private
function __handle_global_suman {

  # I want $1 to be node exec args and $2 to be args to node script
  node ${NODE_EXEC_ARGS} ${Z}/cli.js ${ORIGINAL_ARGS};

}
```

hopefully you see what I am trying to do and can help, thanks

Comment: Also, if there is a way to make the __handle_global_suman function truly private, that would be a nicety

Comment: You can't assign an array to a string without losing argument-boundary information. `ORIGINAL_ARGS="$@"` is thus inherently broken -- only an array, not a string, can store that value safely. See http://shellcheck.net/ for the more pedestrain quoting errors.

Comment: ...there's also a bunch of general-purpose bad practice here. The `function` keyword is needlessly incompatible with baseline POSIX sh shells (unlike most bash extensions, adding no value over the portable form, which is `suman() {` with no preceding `function`), and all-uppercase variable names are reserved by POSIX-specified convention for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell.

Comment: (rather, POSIX explicitly specifies that *environment* variables with meaning to tools it specifies are all-caps, and that all lower-case environment variables are reserved for application use -- but since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, the only way to be certain one isn't overwriting an environment variable with meaning to the system is to steer clear of the namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below, we're passing an argument list stored in a local variable by reference:

```
suman() {
   local -a args=( --inspect --debug-brk )
   __handle_global_suman args "$@"
}

__handle_global_suman() {
   local ref="$1[@]"; shift
   node "${!ref}" "${Z}/cli.js" "$@"
}
```

---

Why is this different? Because we could also pass:

```
local -a args=( --inspect --argument-with-spaces="hello cruel world" )
```

...and it `--argument-with-spaces=...` would be passed correctly, as exactly one argument.

Comment: huh, how does local get passed from suman to __handle_global_suman?

Comment: it would be neat if that local keyword worked for functions, then we could make a private function ?

Comment: Right. `local` is a keyword that makes your variables, well, local -- even if declared inside a function, all shell variables are global unless `declare`, `typeset` or `local` is used in their declaration.

Comment: it would be neat if that local keyword worked for functions, then we could make a private function ?

Comment: No, you can't make a private function, but... frankly, I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: eh just to avoid polluting global namespace...I am sure there have been some nasty nasty nasty bugs out there somewhere because of global namespace conflicts in bash, I don't even want to think about it

Comment: Definitely true, but if you're making a habit of prefixing your names and are testing for leaks from your functions (see for instance the leak-checking code I have in https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash), you've probably got most of it covered.

Comment: yeah I agree, one last question - why did you put double quotes around "${Z}/cli.js"?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, what if `Z` has spaces or wildcard characters in it, or contains a character present in the current definition of `IFS`? Putting double quotes around expansions prevents them from doing surprising things, and thus reduces the number of potential corner cases / bugs one has to think about when reading code.

Comment: ok got it. unfortunately this answer is not quite working for me...are you sure you didn't mean __handle_global_suman $args "$@"  or __handle_global_suman "$args" "$@" ? I tried all of these, and none worked. By "none worked", I mean the first argument inside __handle_global_suman did not get interpreted by the node executable correctly

Comment: I will log "${!ref}" for you one sec

Comment: Positive that I meant exactly what I wrote -- for that matter, I actually tested it on bash 3.2 myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129080/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-alexander-mills).

Comment: Ok nevermind I got it working, assuming this is more correct, I will accept your answer instead

Comment: Given that the [local](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-local) array defined in `suman` is available by name inside the called function `__handle_global_suman`, you could avoid using the variable name in the call and the `${!ref}` notation in called function; it could simply refer to `"${args[@]}"`, could it not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sure, but that's a tighter coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a little unclear, but I think I get the gist: word splitting isn't working as you expected in Bash.

You need to quote the ${NODE_EXEC_ARGS} parameter to you second function, since in the case that it is whitespace it will be stripped out and wont form a parameter to the called function:

```
__handle_global_suman "${NODE_EXEC_ARGS}" ${ORIGINAL_ARGS}
```

Also the ${ORIGINAL_ARGS} var is redundant in your example. You should just pass "$@" directly:

```
__handle_global_suman "${NODE_EXEC_ARGS}" "$@"
```

The second proposed alternative solution definitely *isn't* necessary, definitely is bad practice and you can definitely achieve what you want with Bash function parameter passing.

Comment: so if I quote the arguments, then they will get passed properly to the __handle_global_suman function?

Comment: this is not really working for me, can you let me know what isn't clear in the original question? I am just trying to pass arguments directly from one function to another without using global vars

Comment: Well, I meant you could have stripped it back to isolate exactly the problem you having. Like what's a "suman" etc. But I get the general jist, your bumping up against a word splitting issue.

Comment: re: "You also want to probably not quote the $1 when you pass it to node since it multiple args:" Yes, I agree, I will edit the original question to fix that so it's not a distraction.

Comment: You answer has helped me, but it ultimately doesn't answer the original question which is - the arguments being passed "__handle_global_suman ${NODE_EXEC_ARGS} ${ORIGINAL_ARGS}", are not available inside the __handle_global_suman function (they are not there at all).

Comment: Have you confirmed something is actually being passed to `sumar`? Stuff this in each function `i=1; for j in "$@"; do echo "P$i='$j'"; i=$(($i+1)); done` to see what "$@" actually contains.

Comment: `$ORIGINAL_ARGS` is not just redundant, it's broken. `"foo bar" "baz qux"` won't be kept as two words when passed that way, nor will `"*.txt"` retain its quoting.

Comment: I got it working with nothing more than the help from this answer, basically by quoting the arguments passed to the __handle_global_suman function, and then *not* quoting them inside the __handle_global_suman function

Comment: btw, you have no idea how stripped down this example is :) I removed a lot of code

Comment: @AlexanderMills, if not quoting inside the function is "fixing your problem", you've got other bugs -- such as being unable to pass arguments with spaces in them or globs quoted to avoid expansion -- which will be solved by switching from strings to arrays for the relevant variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the heads up, can you see the answer I just posted and let me know if what you just said applies and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me, thanks to the help @S.Pinkus whose answer I upvoted since the information contained in the answer was all I needed to fix the problem. Note the below works, but that @CDhuffy's answer is in theory more generic and therefore better.

```
function suman {

   __handle_global_suman "--inspect --debug-brk" "$@"

}

function __handle_global_suman {

   # ${1} is "--inspect --debug-brk"
   # ${2} is whatever I passed to the suman function
   node ${1}  ${Z}/cli.js ${2};

}
```

bash is awesome ;) ...not

Comment: This code is buggy. If instead of `--inspect --debug-brk` you wanted to pass `--foo="bar baz"`, it wouldn't work for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I see, can you mention a fix?

Comment: Which specific version of bash? I'd be tempted to use namevars if you're targeting 4.4 or newer.

Comment: let me check, it says "sh-3.2$"

Comment: btw it definitely does *not* work if I just use quotes like so: node "${1}"  ${X}/cli.js "${2}";

Comment: this is for a library so prob need to support as old a possible version of bash as is reasonable

Comment: 3.2 it is, then; I'll have an answer shortly.